# Why does Android Studio resets the LANGUAGE_LEVEL to JDK 1.6 after restart of the project when I manually changed it to JDK 1.8

Tags: android, java-8, java-6

I work on a LibGDX project in Android Studio 1.5 which has an android, core and desktop module. When I change the language level from "LANGUAGE_LEVEL=JDK_1_6" TO "LANGUAGE_LEVEL=JDK_1_8" in the iml files in these respective directories, after restarting the project they changed back to 1.6. However it isn't causing any errors by now and my project is compiling and running

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not support Java 8 yet. Level 7 should work.

Comment: Hi Sascha I follow this book "Learn Android Studio" which uses JDK 1.8.0_25 so I suppose it works with that jdk version. Also it doesn't always change back to 1.6 but sometimes to 1.7 so it seems like a bug right? Still waiting for a solution